# How to declare AuthService inside a module?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, firebase, service

I tried to create a service inside my module **core** by using `ng g s core/auth --m=core` and `ng generate service core/auth --m=core` both of which didn't work.
It gave me this error: **Unknown option:'--m'**
Then, I manually created it inside my core module by naming the file as **auth.service.ts** and wrote this code inside it:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core'
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth'
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app'

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
  constructor(public afAuth: AngularFireAuth){}

  login() {
    this.afAuth.auth.signInWithPopup(new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider())
  }
  logout() {
    this.afAuth.auth.signOut()
  }
}
```

But now, my navigation bar component is not working, and my entire angular app is not loading. I have searched a lot but nothing could be of help. Please guide me.

Comment: Simply use : `ng g s auth`

Comment: can you guide me how I can import it inside my navbar component that is within my shared module?

Comment: I've included an answer, by performing those steps you should be able to create a service in the respective module.

Comment: If you're going to use the `m` option to indicate what module to use when generating a service, you only use one dash: `-m`, not two: `--m`. Two dashes are needed when using the full option name: `--module`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perform the following steps:

1. cd to the path of the module where you want to create the service.
2. Type in : `ng generate service auth`

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked like a charm. I had no idea that we can do it using this method :)